# How to color the 3D points cloud

Tags: python, matlab, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

I've tried to do 3d reconstruction using multiple images and I also have my camera intrinsics params. I used SFM in Matlab the 3D points are the same color, I wonder how can I visualize the 3D points in their own color similar to the color in images. any help would be really appreciated. And also if you know of some implementation for 3d reconstruction from multiple images in Matlab or Python please recommend. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

h = plot( result, );

for example:

```
h = plot( fitresult,'b');
```

here is more info:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html#f30-448776_sep_mw_3a76f056-2882-44d7-8e73-c695c0c54ca8